# Get Specific Rect of UIImage

Tags: iphone, colors, uiimage, pixel, editing

Need to fit a UIImage for its frame(which is also a UIImage in own), as frame's thickness is unknown. Images are attached .

How can we detect the rect of same UIColor in UIImage ?

Answer (score 0):

For getting the frame of ain image is as easy as this:

```
CGRect myFrame = myUIImageView.frame;
```

Is this what you are asking for?

Comment: Don't think so: he's asking about the rect of same UIColor - i guess he wants to substract the thickness of visible frame on the image (not layer's frame).

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage *img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimagename.png(any)"];
```

You can make use of it to set frame as image frames,

```
CGRect imageFrame=CGRectMake(x,y,img.size.width,img.size.height);
```

**Note:**

**img.size.width gives you the width of your image    and img.size.height gives you the height of your image**

Answer (score 0):

You could check *the color at pixel (0,0)*. This would be the color of the frame. Then
you'd go 1px down and 1px left until you get different color - that's how you find
frame thickness.

Like so:

```
    self.yourImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"painting-with-border.png"];

    NSLog(@"original size: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(self.yourImage.size));

    BOOL success = NO;
    CGFloat x_frame = 1.0;
    CGFloat y_frame = 1.0;

    CGFloat x_max = self.yourImage.size.width/2.0;
    CGFloat y_max = self.yourImage.size.height/2.0;

    UIColor *frameColor = [self.yourImage colorAtPixel: CGPointMake (1.0,1.0)];

    NSString *hexFrameColor = [frameColor hexStringFromColor];
    NSLog (@"frame color: %@", hexFrameColor);

    UIColor *testPixelColor;
    NSString *hexTestPixelColor;

    while ((!success) && (x_frame < x_max) && (y_frame < y_max)) {

        x_frame = x_frame + 1.0;
        y_frame = y_frame + 1.0;

        testPixelColor = [self.yourImage colorAtPixel: CGPointMake (x_frame,y_frame)];
        hexTestPixelColor = [testPixelColor hexStringFromColor];

        NSLog(@"color at pixel (%.0f,%.0f): %@", x_frame,y_frame,hexTestPixelColor);

        if (![hexFrameColor isEqualToString: hexTestPixelColor]) {
            success = YES;
            NSLog (@"found frame border at (%.0f,%.0f)", x_frame,y_frame);
        }
    }

    CGRect newFrame;

    if (success) {

        newFrame = CGRectMake(x_frame,y_frame,self.yourImage.size.width-x_frame,self.yourImage.size.height-y_frame);
        NSLog(@"To crop image inside frame use: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(newFrame));


    } else {

        NSLog (@"couldn't define frame width");
    }
```

This method would check the picture for it's frame to the middle of the picture.

Note:

`ColorAtPixel` is not a part of `UIKit`. You can get it in Ole Begemann's [OBShapedButton](https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton).

`hexStringFromColor` is not a part of `UIKit`. It's a category you can find at [uicolor-utilities](https://github.com/ars/uicolor-utilities).

For cropping `UIImage` you can then find many ways here on SO but that's not part of your question.

This code was tested with image:

[image: image with border]

Output was:

original size: {314, 451}

frame color: 980C0C

color at pixel (2,2): 980C0C

color at pixel (3,3): 980C0C

color at pixel (4,4): 980C0C

color at pixel (5,5): 980C0C

color at pixel (6,6): 414429

found frame border at (6,6)

To crop image inside frame use: {{6, 6}, {308, 445}}

**NOTE:** this method will work only if border is made out of exactly the same color. Some borders in (compressed) `.jpg` images might have borders where color slightly variates. For that you should use an algorithm that checks color similarity - but that's completely another topic.

Also this code is written for images with frame of the same thickness at all sides. I'm sure you'll be able to modify the code for cases where thickness of the frame on top/bottom differs from thickness on left/right.

Comment: Is here the "yourImage" is the UIImage's instanse? B'coz the above code gives erroe for the yourImage.frame

Comment: @user1254220: Of course - you can't just copy paste - you have to modify for your code. Also you'll have to download code from those links at the bottom and include appropriate files to your project.

Comment: @user1254220: i modified the code a bit - previous version was typed directly to SO - this one is tested in Xcode.